# Preenchimento dinâmino de formulário com angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

No sistema que eu estou desenvolvendo, vai ter um campo `input` para o usuário pesquisar se tal *CPF* já existe cadastrado no Banco de Dados, se tiver eu quero mostrar todos os dados desse cliente em um formulário já preenchido

Essa é a função que faz a pesquisa no banco de dados e retorna a consulta

```
$scope.PesquisarCpf = function () {

$http.post("http://GetCpf.php", {'cpf':$scope.cliente.cpf,}).
               success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                 $scope.contratos = data;
               }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                 location.href="#/Cliente"

               });
}
```

Comment: E qual é o problema? O que você esta obtendo? Como o que você obtém diverge do esperado?

Comment: Eu obtenho os dados do cliente referente ao tal cpf pesquisado, por exemplo,  </br> CEP: "0000000"
CIDADE: "xxxxx"  </br>  
COMPLEMENTO: "xxxxxx"  </br>
CPF: "123.456.789-99"  </br>
DTNASCIMENTO: "xxxxxx"  </br>
ID_CLIENTE: "1"  </br>
NOME: "xxxxxx"  </br>
NOME_MAE: "xxxxxxxx"  </br>
NOME_PAI: "xxxxxx"  <br/> e esses dados eu quero mostrar em um formulário html

Comment: Pelo que verifiquei você está retornar uma string, toda separada por <br/>, seria interessante se você retornasse um JSON do servidor, assim você poderia fazer bind com o ng-model e exibir cada informação em um campo de input. se não tiver posibilidade você poderia jogar essa string em um campo uma propriedade e fazer bind com um campo de texto.

Answer (score 1):

Para preencher o valor de acordo com o modelo, basta usar a diretiva [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="contratos.cep" />
<input type="text" ng-model="contratos.cidade" />
```

Lembrando que o valor retornado do PHP deve ser um objeto JSON.

Comment: Mas eu quero que mostre dentro dos campos do formulário

Comment: Então, é isso mesmo, postei como exemplo estes campos, que podem estar dentro de um form.

Comment: Você pode fazer assim também `<input type="text" name="cep" value="{{contratos.cep}}">` mas não é o correto.

Answer (score 1):

Imaginando que vc tenha um Input do cpf do usuário no seu form, e a sua function "PesquisarCpf" retorna os dados do usuário.

```html
<input type="text" 
       ng-model="cpf"
       ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" // para ter um delay de um segundo para executar a função
       ng-change="PesquisarCpf(cliente.cpf)" />
```

no seu scope eu só alteraria a passagem de parâmetro, por boas práticas, nunca passe $scope no parâmetro, como pode notar o ng-change passa o parâmetro pela chamada da função, vc tem acesso ao scope no próprio html.

```js
$scope.PesquisarCpf = function (cpf) {

$http.post("http://GetCpf.php", {"cpf": cpf,}).
               success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                 $scope.contratos = data;
               }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                 location.href="#/Cliente"

               });
}
```

Se não ficou claro o exemplo, posso criar para você um exemplo mais prático no Plunker.